# Using FileZilla to connect to an unmapped HDD on home LAN

Tags: networking, ftp

Two upfront confessions:

1. I am a complete noob with this topic. I may have bought a sledgehammer to crack a nut, perhaps FileZilla is the wrong/too powerful tool. A lot of the relevant terminology I just don't know. Leading to confession two...
2. I *have* searched for answers but the ones I have found are either confusing or antique. I am insufficiently expert to tell good ideas from bad, and having had many IT troubles recently I am very reluctant to play with things like the registry editor etc (I'm usually relatively competent, this is just unfamiliar territory). Please be gentle!

**Context:**

- I have recently set up a home mesh network using three ASUS XT8 units (wifi backhaul, Windows 11 Pro). I have attached two 5 TB HDDs, one to each of the wireless nodes. They seem to behave exactly like the test USB drive I plugged directly into the router, so I don't think the router/node difference is the problem. All firmware, BIOS, software, drivers etc are up to date, I'm using my normal Windows account (full admin privileges), and I'm also using the only ASUS router account I have (again, admin).
- I managed to get my PC to "see" the relevant HDDs using the FTP set up in the ASUS software (other methods didn't work). They are listed under "My PC" as folders (not network drives), and appear to be unmappable using the basic Windows options.
- I have tried to add/modify user permissions both at the "ASUS software" side and the "Windows properties" side to no avail. The folders/drives don't have "properties" options in the right click menu of Windows Explorer, unlike normal folders/drives.
- I have been able to access the drives/folders using Windows Explorer, and set up a few basic subfolders using the ASUS software. I have also been able to add a test file, and, in some folders, delete it.

**Problem:**

- I cannot use all folders/subfolders and see no options to change the relevant permissions anywhere. I can only use (via Windows Explorer) one level of folder.
- Trying to move files over to these drives maintains folder structure but does not bring over any files. Folders with (unusable) subfolders are not deletable using the ASUS or Windows software. The only way to remove these subfolders, and files in them, is to plug the drives directly into my PC and reformat them.
- As an experiment, I partitioned the drives into 2 x ~2.5 TB partitions (because of this: https://www.asus.com/uk/support/FAQ/1042680) and there appeared to be no difference in access between that and the single 5 TB partition drives. I have only formatted the drives using NTFS. I have not yet formatted the drives to another format with a greater number of smaller partitions.
- I bought FileZilla because of a stroke of "genius"! I.e. I set this up using an FTP method, so an FTP tool will fix everything. (Told you I was a noob) I have pretty much no idea how to use it, and at least to me, it seems the level of assumed knowledge is above my very low level.

Apologies for what is probably a very basic question, but any help would be very gratefully appreciated.

Comment: "_I bought FileZilla_" - FileZilla is free and open source software. If you bought it then unfortunately you've been ripped off by someone. See https://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: There's a pro version from that site. Which is what I opted for. Just in case!

Comment: No, there isn't. You've been ripped off / you have malware, etc.

Comment: Is this how you set up the FTP: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1011280/ ? To get the path, you should be able to right-click the top-level folders (under "My PC") > properties > Target. It should look something like `ftp://[router address]/folder`, and you can use that path in other ftp clients like FileZilla.

Comment: I recommend that if you're not familiar with unix file permissions, you should manage the folder permissions inside the asus tool instead. If you want Windows to be able to understand the permissions better, set up those drives as a "Network Place (Samba) Share" instead of FTP.

Comment: @LouisRedux apologies I have just seen the Pro version available from FileZilla. Unfortunately the additional protocols it provides are irrelevant to the problem you've described

Comment: Does the ASUS management software give you an option to format the drives? I'm thinking they'll probably be Linux-based, in which case NTFS is not an ideal filesystem to use

Comment: @Roaima, No worries :-)

I wasn't sure about the features so I ripped myself off with ignorance!

Comment: ~Cpt.Whale, yes that's how I did the FTP set up, and yes that's how thee addresses etc look. I'll try to figure out how to use FileZilla for that (which TBF has been tricky so far. Again, this is weirdly huge gap in my knowledge.)I got no joy with the Samba method. I've tried to manage permissions in the ASUS software but seem to be getting it wrong/there isn't an option to do what I want. I'll muck about with it some more. Thanks.

Comment: @Roaima, I haven't found a drive formatting option in the ASUS software, again, probably my error. I also hadn't even thought it could be a Linux/Unix system, and, like you say, if so, the manual recommends a non-NTFS format.

ETA: When trying to delete subfolders etc, I get an error message about not being able to delete folders with things in them. I get this all the way to the "bottom" folders. Which is odd to me.

Oh, and Cpt. Whale the last time I used any Unix at all was ~25+ years ago when programming NMR machines! I'm a tad out of date. ;-)

Comment: 1/2 Looks like GPT with one or two ext4 filesystems would be your best bet. See https://event.asus.com/2009/networks/disksupport/ (top row) and section 3.6 of the [user guide](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/ZenWiFi_XT8/E17527_ZenWiFi_AX_XT8_UM_v2_WEB.pdf?model=ASUS%20ZenWiFi%20AX%20(XT8)). To configure read/write access permissions you then need to follow page 41 _et seq_ where it talks about setting up Samba (the Windows file sharing subsystem for Linux-based devices).

Comment: 2/2 That'll give you direct network access from the Windows systems as (for example) `\\myrouter\myshare` rather than fiddling around with FileZilla

Comment: If this answers your question I'll elaborate (a little) in an answer that you can accept

Comment: Hi Roaima and Cpt.Whale,

1) I have FTP via Filezilla working now. I have no idea why the basics weren't working, before. I restarted the universe from factory settings ;-) , and FTP. The folder permissions I had before are not present this time. I can only use FTP with folders I have given permission to use in the ASUS software.

2) I cannot link any of the folders to Windows Explorer at all. Unlike the previous situation where I could at least look at folders. I am refused access via Windows Explorer, regardless of permissions settings, passwords etc.

Comment: 3) Samba: Using either the FTP address or Samba I now cannot link any folder to Windows Explorer or a network place and access it. If there is any way to get these drives working via Samba (and then be able to be used as simple network drives) that would be my preference, but for now, FTP is working well via FileZilla (fast, file transferred, not just folder structure). Now I have to work out how to make it secure etc.

Roaima, I have tried your suggestions, no luck yet, I'm going to try something more "serious" now.

Comment: P.S. Roaima, I had followed the instructions you listed prior to posting the questions, but to no avail. This was with formatted/partitioned drives BUT only the file formats available in Windows. IIRC some of the exFAT ones were not present. I subsequently did as suggested but not *yet* got the desired results. A couple more things to try...

(Googling has revealed much about Merlin vs standard ASUS firmware and SMBv1 etc. Mucking around with this also did nothing, I am reluctant to leave SMBv1 operational for security reasons. I am also trying to ensure my FTP accessible drives are secure)